# Overriding return type in function template specialization

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to specialize a function template such that the return type changes depending on the type of the template argument.

```
class ReturnTypeSpecialization
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    T Item();
};

// Normally just return the template type
template<typename T>
T ReturnTypeSpecialization::Item() { ... }

// When a float is specified, return an int
// This doesn't work:
template<float>
int ReturnTypeSpecialization::Item() { ... }
```

Is this possible? I can't use C++11.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want a function to return the type that is provided as a template argument, except in one special case I want the function to return a different type.

Comment: Just for the record: If the template argument is being deduced from the type of an argument, rather than explicitly specified, an easier way to accomplish returning a different type is to use a function overload.  (Of course that won't work in this example because there are no arguments)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Since the specialization has to agree with the base template on the return type, you can make it so by adding a "return type trait", a struct you can specialize and draw the true return type from:

```
// in the normal case, just the identity
template<class T>
struct item_return{ typedef T type; };

template<class T>
typename item_return<T>::type item();

template<>
struct item_return<float>{ typedef int type; };
template<>
int item<float>();
```

[Live example.](https://ideone.com/NSGksm)

Note that you might want to stick to the following, so you only need to update the return-type in the `item_return` specialization.

```
template<>
item_return<float>::type foo<float>(){ ... }
// note: No `typename` needed, because `float` is not a dependent type
```

Comment: Make sure all specializations are declared before they might be instantiated.  Practically speaking, this means the specialization MUST be declared in the same header file, and the declarations ought to be as close together as possible.

Comment: @aschepler: Very good point. Fiddling around with specializations in this form is pretty volatile.

Comment: don't you mean dependent name?

Comment: The `type` in `trait<T>::type` would be a dependent name if `T` was a dependent type, i.e. a template parameter or a type derived from a template parameter. "Derived" here means like `typedef std::pair<A, B> T;` where `A` and/or `B` is a template parameter.

Comment: @didierc: Well, a dependent type in C++ can also depend on a value... if it's a dependent value. ;) Either a (non-type) template parameter, again, or any value derived from a template parameter. There are dependent types, dependent values, and dependent names.

Comment: Type traits and this `typedef` trick were entirely new to me. I feel enlightened. Thank you!

Comment: "_the specialization has to agree with the base template on the return type_" why?

Answer (score 8):

You can do template specializations like so:

```
template<typename T>
T item() {
    return T();
}

template<>
float item<float>() {
    return 1.0f;
}
```

Comment: This would imply that `T` is also the always the return type, which from the example in the question, doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @Zeta: You can fully specialize them (also called *explicit specialization*).

Comment: @Xeo: Title of the question: *"
Overriding return type in function template specialization
"*. Probably a typo in the question's content.

Comment: @Xeo yeah you're right this would imply that `T` is the return type.

Comment: So with this method, the gist or 'catch' would be that one would be required to explicitly specialize the template for each return type? Is that right? Is it also right that the accepted answer allows one to sort-of dynamically over-ride the return type from a single specialization or two?

In terms of efficiency but at compile and runtime -> wouldn't this method be better? 

Edit - I see - its really not better for the asker because of their use case. But your answer helped me out more efficiently. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Do all of the specialization in a worker class and use a simple function as a wrapper that will be specialized implicitly.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

// worker class -- return a reference to the given value
template< typename V > struct worker
   {
   typedef V const & type;
   static type get( V const & v ) { return v; }
   };

// worker class specialization -- convert 'unsigned char' to 'int'
template<> struct worker<unsigned char>
   {
   typedef int type;
   static type get( unsigned char const & v ) { return v; }
   };

// mapper function
template< typename V > typename worker<V>::type mapper( V const & v )
   {
   return worker<V>::get(v);
   }

int main()
   {
   char a='A';
   unsigned char b='B';
   cout << "a=" << mapper(a) << ", b=" << mapper(b) << "\n";
   }
```

In this example, the specialization of `unsigned char` causes it to be converted to an `int` so that `cout` will display it as a number instead of as a character, generating the following output...

```
a=A, b=66
```

Comment: This has the same underlying mechanics as @Xeo's answer, but might be considered a little bit cleaner since there is only one specialization required.  Another feature, as implemented, is that the normal case is essentially a NOP -- it simply returns a reference to the original value.

Comment: I like this solution, too.  If you want to specifically disallow the generic solution and only allow explicit templates, the first struct can be changed to just `template< typename V > struct worker;`, no body.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you could use the following hack. Given these simple type traits:

```
template<bool b, typename T, typename U>
struct conditional { typedef T type; };

template<typename T, typename U>
struct conditional<false, T, U> { typedef U type; };

template<typename T, typename U>
struct is_same { static const bool value = false; };

template<typename T>
struct is_same<T, T> { static const bool value = true; };
```

You could write your class and specialized member function as follows:

```
class ReturnTypeSpecialization
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    typename conditional<is_same<T, float>::value, int, T>::type 
    Item();
};

// Normally just return the template type
template<typename T>
typename conditional<is_same<T, float>::value, int, T>::type
ReturnTypeSpecialization::Item() { return T(); }

// When a float is specified, return an int
template<>
int ReturnTypeSpecialization::Item<float>() { return 1.0f; }
```

Simple test program (uses C++11 just for verification):

```
int main()
{
    ReturnTypeSpecialization obj;
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(obj.Item<bool>()), bool>::value, "!");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(obj.Item<float>()), int>::value, "!");
}
```

Here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1VtHEF%2429).

Comment: @Rapptz: OK, sorry I missed that. But I believe this could be rewritten without using any C++11 feature (`std::conditional` is not hard to rewrite)

Comment: I think you got your condition the wrong way around. Also, this is pretty boilerplate-y to extend to more specializations and even worse, all specializations must be known before-hand.

Comment: `// When a float is specified, return an int`, but you specialize for `int` and return `float`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I tried to use the template specialization for returning the parameter value for primitives as well as std::string data, while doing so I was getting lot of unresolved external, redefinition kind of errors.
so if any one face something like this, he/she can use something like below when want to return different data types including string,
**NOTE**: both the Template function must be the part of the Header file (*.h)...
so we are using template specialization string data type here...
inside class as a inline member we have to use template specialize method and in the same file we can define the template as well.

```
class ConfigFileParser
{
public:
    bool ParseConfigFile(const std::string& file_name);
    template <typename T>
    T GetParameterValue(const std::string key);
    template <>
    std::string GetParameterValue<std::string>(const std::string key)
    {
        std::string param_val = "";
        //do logical operation here... 
        return param_val;
    }
private:
    // private functions...

    // private data...
};

template <typename T>
T ConfigFileParser::GetParameterValue(const std::string key)
{
    T param_val = 0;
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string val_str;
    // do some operation here...
    ss << val_str.c_str();
    ss >> param_val;

    return param_val;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

With help of C++23 you can do it with less code:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
std::type_identity_t<T> bar();

template<>
std::type_identity_t<float> bar<float>() {return {}; }

template<>
std::type_identity_t<int> bar<int>() {return {}; }
```

Comment: The OP said they can't use C++11 or later.