# Is it possible to change return type of a specialized template function?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Here is what I'd like to do:

```
template<int I> struct banana {
    float number;
    banana(float n) {
        number = n;
    }

    int getNumber() { 
        return number; 
    }
};

template<> float banana<0>::getNumber() {
    return number;
}
```

so when a new banana<0> gets made, it returns the number as a float instead of an integer. The compiler won't let me though.

I found an answer to seemingly the same question https://stackoverflow.com/a/15912228/4049658 (all though, I can use c++ 11 but not 14 if that makes a difference) but I don't understand how it works or if its even the same thing.

Comment: Your code sample looks pretty nonsensical. What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: That doesn't look like a template function to me, more like a normal function in a (templated) class.

Comment: its a minimal illustration of a quality I want to add to my class. The real class is a wrapper around template type data array that should always return floats. Since some of the supported raw data types are integral, i need to reinterpret them so I'm returning a proxy with a setter function defined for assignment operator from the bracket operator.

Comment: So the answer is "yes, but the example code is not a templated function, but rather a templated class".

Comment: `banana<0>` doesn't exist as a separate class, it is just an instantiation of a template (the result of a metafunction). You need to define `banana<0>` as a distinct class (an explicit template specialisation).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easy way to specialize the return type is the use of std::conditional:

```
// First approach: conditional
template<int I> struct banana {
    float number;
    banana(float n) {
        number = n;
    }

    // C++14 std::conditional_t<I == 0, float, int>
    typename std::conditional<I == 0, float, int>::type
    getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
};
```

Or as you suggested you could use template specialization:

```
template<int /*I*/>
struct banana_return_type
{
    using type = int;
};

template<>
struct banana_return_type<0>
{
    using type = float;
};

template<int I> struct bananaSecond {
    float number;
    bananaSecond(float n) {
        number = n;
    }

    typename banana_return_type<I>::type
        getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/202e4caf004e9bff)

Comment: I think it would be useful to mention that, for both solutions, you can now write an explicit specialization the way the OP wanted, that is, something like `template<> inline float banana<0>::getNumber() { std::cout << "spec\n"; return number; }`, in order to provide a different definition for the special case `0`. Explaining why it works now, why it didn't work for the code in the question, and why `inline` may be needed would make the answer complete, I think. Nitpicking: the OP mentioned he can't use C++14, so `std::conditional_t` is not available.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
template<int I> struct banana {
    float number;
    banana(float n) {
        number = n;
    }

    int getNumber() { 
        return number; 
    }
};
```

At this point, `banana<0>` is not a distinct user-defined class, but an instantiation of a template, so the following is illformed:

```
template<> float banana<0>::getNumber() {
    return number;
}
```

You need to make `banana<0>` is a distinctly defined class: **an explicit template specialisation**.

```
template<> struct banana<0> {
    float number;
    banana(float n) {
        number = n;
    }

    float getNumber() { 
        return number; 
    }
};
```