# Why does this function template specialisation not compile?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I'm trying to specialise a templatised function inside a templatised class. It works fine until I add the specialisation: then it doesn't compile anymore.

Here's a simplified example of what kind of thing I'm trying to do:

```
template <typename TString, typename TStringStream, typename TChar>
class TestClass
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    static T convert(const TChar* text);
};


//This specialisation doesn't compile
template <typename TString, typename TStringStream, typename TChar>
template <>
inline bool TestClass<TString, TStringStream, TChar>::convert(const TChar* text)
{
    return strcmp(text, "true");
}


template <typename TString, typename TStringStream, typename TChar>
template <typename T>
T TestClass<TString, TStringStream, TChar>::convert(const TChar* text)
{
    TStringStream textStream(text);
    T result;
    textStream >> result;
    return result;
}


void main()
{
    TestClass<RString, RStringstream, char>::convert<bool>("0");
}
```

This is the compiler error Visual Studio 2010 returns when I try to compile this:

```
error C2244: 'TestClass<TString,TStringStream,TChar>::convert' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
    definition
    'bool TestClass<TString,TStringStream,TChar>::convert(const TChar *)'
    existing declarations
    'T TestClass<TString,TStringStream,TChar>::convert(const TChar *)'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

(This question is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911890/overriding-return-type-in-function-template-specialization) because in that link they are trying to return a different type from what the template is, a very special case that I am not trying to do here.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding return type in function template specialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911890/overriding-return-type-in-function-template-specialization)

Comment: My question is different because in that link they are trying to return a different type from what the template is, a very special case that I am not trying to do here.

Comment: ick, don't do `void main`

Comment: lol just typed that quickly for the example, obviously this code is part of a bigger whole :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your source is not valid C++, `template<>` cannot follow a template parameter list.

The template `TestClass<TString, TStringStream, TChar>::convert` can also be fully specialized, but only for a given instance of `TestClass<TString, TStringStream, TChar>`. Such as:

```
template <>
template <>
inline bool TestClass<RString, RStringstream, char>::convert<bool>(const char* text)
{
    return text == "true";
}
```

Comment: If you need partial specialization, you have to do it through a class. Or, you could just do an overload instead.

Comment: Overload doesn't work if it is the return value that changes while the parameters remain the same.

Answer (score 4):

> **[temp.expl.spec]/16** In an explicit specialization declaration for a member of a class template or a member template that appears in namespace scope, the member template and some of its enclosing class templates may remain unspecialized, except that the declaration shall not explicitly specialize a class member template if its enclosing class templates are not explicitly specialized as well... [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> template <class Y> template <>
> void A<Y>::B<double>::mf2() { } // ill-formed; B<double> is specialized but
>                                 // its enclosing class template A is not
> ```
>
> —*end example* ]

Basically, anything that starts with `template<something> template</*nothing*/>` is ill-formed.