# template class different return type depends of class parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, specialization

I have class like this:

```
template<class T>
class A{
   // lots of methods here

   Something get();
};
```

I want `Something get()` to become `const Something &get()` if T is specific class.

First I tried to do it with inheritance, but it got too messy.

Can I do so, without specializing whole `class A` and without introducing second template.

Comment: maybe std::enable_if would help you in this instance? Some kind of SFINAE solution.

Comment: You need to use template specialization. However you might not have to specialize the entirety of A. You _could_ have a little trick where Something get() is in a templated class B. You can specialize that and have A inherit from it to get the intended form of the function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding return type in function template specialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911890/overriding-return-type-in-function-template-specialization)

Answer (score 6):

You just write it down in a simple, easy-to-use English-like language.

```
std::conditional<std::is_same<T, SpecificClass>::value, 
                 Something const&, 
                 Something>::type get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::conditional` like explained by n.m., or, if you need different behavior for the methods you can use `std::enable_if`:

```
struct Something { };

template<typename T>
class Foo
{
  Something something;
public:
  template<typename U = T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<U, float>::value, int>::type = 0> Something get() {
    std::cout << "not specialized called" << std::endl;
    return something;
  }

  template<typename U = T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, float>::value, int>::type = 0> const Something& get() {
    std::cout << "specialized called" << std::endl;
    return something;
  }
};


Something sm1 = Foo<float>().get();
Something sm2 = Foo<int>().get();
```