# check return type from templated method

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, return-type-deduction

I am working on c++11 application:

There I have some templated methods:

```
template <class P, class T>
void copyMemberToDocument(const P &childClass
                          std::string (T::*getter) (void) const) {
   auto member = (childClass.*getter)();
   // ...
}
```

Child class has multiple inheritance so I can have something like:

```
class A {
public:
  int getA() {return 1;}

class B {
public:
  const char* getB() {return "hello";}

class C : public A, public B {};
```

So I can do something like:

```
C c;
copyMemberToDocument(c, &B::getB);
copyMemberToDocument(c, &A::getA);
```

Is is possible to know if return value in templated method  will be "const char*" or "int" in order to do different things depending on that?

Comment: this might be helpfull: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911890/overriding-return-type-in-function-template-specialization#15912228

Comment: But that solution would make me to have one specialized template for each return type, right?

Comment: You seem to be missing a comma in your definition of `copyMemberToDocument`. You are also restricting it to methods returning `std::string`, so it can't be called with either `&A::getA` or `&B::getB`

Comment: Did you actually try the code ? The second template parameter is a member function that return std::string. You cannot use different return type unless you template it and then you know the type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct implementation is:

```
template <class P, class T>
void copyMemberToDocument(const P childClass, T getter) {
   static_assert(std::is_member_function_pointer<T>::value,
                 "getter is not a member function."); 
   using member_type = decltype((std::declval<P>().*getter)());
   member_type member = (childClass.*getter)();
 }
```

Now, if you need different code executed, depending on the type `member_type`, you can use overloading of function, class specialisation or c++17's `if constexpr`.

```
if constexpr(std::is_same_v<int,member_type>) {
   std::cout<<"I am a int member\n";
}
if constexpr(std::is_same_v<std::string,member_type>) {
   std::cout<<"I am a string member\n";
}
```

You may have to use `std::remove_reference`.

Comment: Now, is it possible to ask member for its type?

Comment: What do you mean by asking for its type. The type is member_type. If you don't need it before calling the member function, you can use decltype(member).

Comment: If getter method can return std::string, int or std::pair, how can I know the "real" type. This is what I meant

Comment: What do you mean by "know" ? You want to execute different code based on the returned type ?

Comment: I made a generic answer but a pseudo-code of what you are trying to achieve would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic *function overloading*:

```
void something(const char*) { /* ... */ }
void something(int)         { /* ... */ }

template <class P, class T>
void copyMemberToDocument(const P &childClass
                          std::string (T::*getter) (void) const) {
   auto member = (childClass.*getter)();
   something(member);
}
```